# "The donated books to ~" vs "The books donated to ~"

Tags: participles, adjectivals

Is there any difference in meaning between,

> "This is about the **donated books** to our library"

and

> "This is about the **books donated** to our library"?

In the following problem, is it only the meaning making "**donating**" the right answer?

> Please read the following guidelines for [donate] books to our library.

Isn't it a presumption, though it's very likely that way, but is there any grammatical reason not to say "**donated**" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's possible to place the word **donated** before or after **books** depending on the construction of the sentence.

So it's idiomatic to say both:

> We are grateful for the books donated to our library
>   and
>   The purchased books should be placed on the table and the donated books on the desk

In the examples you give, the first is possible but the second is more idiomatic.

However, the following two statements mean different things:

> Please read the following guidelines for donating books to our library.

These guidelines concern the giving of books to the library - for example, which books the library might accept.

> Please read the following guidelines for donated books to our library.

These guidelines concern books that are given to the library - for example, whether the library might choose to sell or recycle some of them.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that the word *donated* at first is an adjective for a noun - book.

But the second word *donated* it has a passive implication.

Comment: True. Thank you. I agree with what you say. I'm sorry that I edited my question, but I still want to know the possibility of "donated" instead of "donating" for the "guidelines" example.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's sentences (and also the accepted answer) are mixing up the verb "to donate" and the adjective "donated".

You can use "to" after the verb, but not after the adjective. In some languages you can say the equivalent of "The donated-to-the-library books" where "donated-to-the-library" functions as an adjective describing "books", but you can't say that in English.

In "This is about the donated books to our library," "donated" is an adjective describing "books". If you remove the adjective, it is clear you can't use the word "to". "This is about the books to our library" doesn't make sense. The sentence should be something like "This is about the donated books *in* our library".

In "This is about the books donated to our library," "donated" is a verb followed by "to". The complete phrase "donated to our library" describes the which books the sentence refers to.

In "Please read the guidelines for […] books to our library, the […] must be a verb, not an adjective. As in the previous example, if it was an adjective you could remove it from the sentence, but in "Please read the guidelines for books to our library" the word "to" doesn't make sense.

In "Please read the guidelines for donating books to our library," the guidelines are about the process of donating books (for example what types of books are acceptable). In a sentence like "Please read the guidelines for donated books in our library," the guidelines are presumably about the fact that there are different procedures which apply to the donated and non-donated books *after* they have been donated.

Comment: Thank you. I understood that it's nicer to say "~ guidelines for books donated to our library," but as  Ronald Sole says when there's a need to distinguish from other types of books, "donated books" is the way to say it, and there might be a time that you need to distinguish "the donated books to the adult section of the library" and "the donated books to the children section of the library."